# How to prevent specific files from an R package to be pushed/uploaded to Github?

Tags: r, git, github, privacy, r-package

For safety reasons, in my own R packages, how to have private files like .Renviron only available locally and prevent from being pushed to GitHub?

Comment: You can use .gitignore

Comment: or you can use `git add file_name.R` instead of `git add .` and add the specific files instead of all files. I would personally use both methods, the .gitignore` as well as adding only the files which you want to push to github.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. If any of you wants to write the answer, I will accept it.